# mail Fetch Bounces errors

Tags: email

I have got everything else working but I get the following error from the Fetch Bounces scheduled job (in the scheduled job log)

> Full message:  Finished execution of Fetch Bounces with result:
>   Failure, Error message: A fatal error was triggered: Could not connect
>   to MailStore for return@downham.org.uk@downham.org.uk.mail.aa.net.uk
>
> Error message:
>
> Empty mail protocol

I'm running on WordPress at a hosting provider. I've checked that I can access the mail server from elsewhere, re-entered the data in case of a typo. Tried POP as well as IMAP, with/without SSL. Also tried with Google mail server instead. Finally I tried from one of the Drupal CiviCRM demo servers and it worked from there. I also tried telneting into the IMAP server from the hosting site and that worked fine so can't be a network issue. So it looks like either its a WordPress issue or something about the hosting provider configuration.

Any suggestions as to where to look next?

Many thanks - Mick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My sense is that this is more likely to be a hosting/configuration issue than a Wordpress issue. Though it could of course be a hosting issue that only affects Wordpress sites :p.  Did you try testing on http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/?

'Empty mail protocol' is from the more helpful end of the error message spectrum.

I would first check on this page civicrm/admin/mailSettings?reset=1 that the **protocol** is set for the processor you are using for **Bounce processing**.

If and when you have ruled out any issues there, it would be time to start digging a little deeper...

---

*Hopefully you don't have to read this far, but just in case...*

Depending on your willingness to jump into the code case, the next step would be to look through the code of the Fetch Bounces scheduled job. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/Job.php#L356 passes of to https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php quite quickly.

It looks like your error message is being generated here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php#L165 and here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Mailing/MailStore.php#L57.

So the question is, why isn't $protocols[$dao->protocol] set on https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Mailing/MailStore.php#L56?

Happy to expand on this answer if necessary.

Comment: Thanks - yes went down that route and found that I'd got two default mail accounts - I'd created a new one when I thought I had edited the example one. Deleting the example one solved the problem!